# How is that possible in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

I've just noticed something that is very counterintuitive for me when it comes to Java generics. Let's look at this method:

```
public static <T> void inspect(T a, T b) { // ... }
```

The following invocation **is** possible:

```
inspect(new Integer(3), new String("What? How?"))
```

I thought that once the type T is deduced, it must be consistent, like two Strings or two Integers.
It doesn't make much sense, because if for example I have in my method the following line:

```
T tmp
```

what is T?

Can someone explain?

Comment: You've let the compiler infer `T`, which means it tries to find the narrowest type that matches both `Integer` and `String`. According to IntelliJ using Java 21, the type inferred is actually a union type: `java.io.Serializable & Comparable<? extends java.io.Serializable & Comparable<?> & java.lang.constant.Constable & java.lang.constant.ConstantDesc> & java.lang.constant.Constable & java.lang.constant.ConstantDesc`. And that fits the bounds of `T`.

Comment: Of course, if the types of the arguments had no interfaces in common and no closer common superclass, there would always be `Object`.

Comment: In fact, this method's signature can be simplified to `public static void inspect(Object a, Object b)`, and it would take the same possible sets of arguments as yours -- any set of arguments that can be passed to your signature can be passed to this signature, since any instance of `T` is also an instance of `Object`; and any set of arguments that can be passed to this signature can be passed to your signature, because the `T` in your signature can be chosen to be `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

The main result is that `Integer` and `String` are both implemented from `Serializable`.

So your code is equal to this:

```java
public static <T extends Serializable> void inspect(T a, T b) {
    System.out.println(a + "_" + b);
}
```

If you change to blow code, it will only work in the `Integer` or `Number` subclasses.

```java
public static <T extends Number> void inspect(T a, T b) {
    System.out.println(a + "_" + b);
}
```

Here is a better example:

```java
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void demo() {
        inspect(new FirstSon("a"), new SecondSon("b"));
    }

    public <T> void inspect(T a, T b) {
        System.out.println(a + "_" + b);
    }


    interface Parent {
    }

    static class FirstSon implements Parent {
        private String name;

        public FirstSon(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    static class SecondSon implements Parent {
        private String name;

        public SecondSon(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```